# Raspberry Pi 4 booting, displaying recover4.elf and recovery.elf not found, then the screen turns off

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi, raspbian

[Message's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ojUW.jpg)

Hi, I've been using this Raspberry for a while, and have had it running octopi for at almost a year. The other day, after installing PiVPN on it, and then rebooting it(I had already rebooted it before so I don't think that's the problem), it stopped working completely, it didn't even show up on the network. I plugged it onto a monitor(by the way the HDMI_1 isn't working), and it displayed this message and then the screen turned blank. The green light is only on some times, but it's not blinking. After some research I believe it's a firmware problem, but I don't know what to do. The reset USB port-power 1000 ms message stopped after I disconnected the keyboard and mouse. I've already tried using another SD card, with octopi, with the same result. I have also tried the SD card in a model B+ and worked fine.

Raspberry Pi 4 - 4GB, with LAN, power and mini-HDMI(through an adapter to HDMI and the to DVI-D) connected.

I am stuck and I don't know what to do, would really appreciate help.

Comment: try to use the Raspberry Pi Imager: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads, and reflash another sd card, might help even though you tried another sd card (already flashed)

Comment: Thanks, will try.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't help

Comment: The errors are pretty much the same, though the new photo has more lines and has better quality

Comment: hmmm, maybe try this: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/#:~:text=Raspberry%20Pi%20Imager%20provides%20an%20easy,and%20resume%20using%20your%20Raspberry%20Pi

Comment: that link has instructions on how to reprogram the eeprom

Comment: Not that it helps.. but I read online that the messages about the bootloader not finding recovery4.elf and recovery.elf are entirely normal - it will only find those when you are using the EEPROM recovery mode.  Something else is wrong and I think those errors are a red herring.

Comment: @KetZoomer i have already tried that with the exact same results

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I have read those as well

Comment: @DaniFG Did you ever figure out what was happening? I'm seeing the exact same thing on my Pi 4.